# How do you get dimensions of svg using raphaeljs

Tags: svg, raphael

I have:

```
<div id = 'my_div' style='width:200px;height:200px;'></div>
<script>
  var my_paper = Raphael( "my_div" ) ;

  // then I jquery.ajax(...) to retrieve a remote .svg file ... 
  //     the svg is delivered as an xml-formatted object

  var my_set = my_paper.importSVG( the_xml_object );
</script>
```

there are **3** things for which I would like to get the width:

1 - the paper .............. EASY ... use: my_paper.width

2 - the set .................. EASY ... use: my_set.getBBox().width

3 - the svg element .... HOW to do this using raphael?

I have found that I can directly access the the_xml_object, and get the info from the svg element, but I want to do it using raphael library.

Comment: As I understand it, Raphael uses a paper object to wrap the SVG or Canvas elements. So, if you're using an SVG capable browser, the paper dimensions are the same as the SVG dimensions.

Comment: sounds good ... BUT: the paper dimensions are based on the html container. So if I have a `<div id="container" style="width:100px"></div>`, then the paper's width is 100. BUT I could be importing a 450x450 .svg document into that area.

Comment: I see your point. I think the `svg` element fills 100% of the containing `div` unless you specify otherwise. When you load a bunch of shapes (paths, circles, etc) then that's not the svg element, they would be groups of elements (path, circle, rect etc) within the SVG element. For Raphael, I think that's a set.

Comment: Ever so slightly off-topic but did you know about Snap SVG? http://snapsvg.io/ It's written by the same chap as Raphael and is for more modern browsers only (it drops IE6/7 support). It's got the backing of Adobe so *might* be more future proof. Just adding that as a helpful thing in case you don't care about IE6/7.

Comment: thanks ... if I have a chance to do another interactive-svg project I will revisit the list of svg-libraries to see what is available (though raphael hasn't been bad). ... the only 'bad' thing so far is I have had to add multiple plugins to extend raphael's functionality (which some people might consider a good thing). ... had to add a import_svg_classic.js, raphael_free_transform.js, raphaeljs-infobox.js